# Sonarqube plugin for Bitbucket as for GitHub

Tags: github, sonarqube

Is there something similar to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin but for Bitbucket cloud?

I would like to run it from Jenkins with gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Other Plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Other+Plugins) section of the documentation, looks like there is a plugin for this: https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin

However, this plugin relies on a deprecated feature of SonarQube (the "preview/issues" mode) - which will be removed in future versions.

Note that SonarSource is currently working on a built-in support of Bitbucket Cloud (pull request analysis included) for its [cloud service called SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io). This built-in support should be available by the end of Q2 2018.

Comment: Should it also work with gradle ? In Prerequisites states
Maven 3.x + JDK 1.7 (to manually build it).
Later configuration is given only for maven. 
Why there is no pull request parameter in configuration , only branch ? Does it look for a pull request for a given branch ?